# How to return value from fs.readFile node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

I have problem with function in function in node.js

```js
function function_1() {
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('date.json', function(err, content) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var parseJson = JSON.parse(content);

        fs.writeFile('date.json', JSON.stringify(parseJson), function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        })
    })

    return parseJson;
}
```

I had no idea how to return value from the file out of my reading function.I tried many things but I failed.I am just starting with node.js.I will be thankfull for every advice.

Comment: You can't.  Use `fs.readFileSync()` instead.

Answer (score -2):

First you may want to add your requirement as a constant at the beginning of the file, that's not mandatory but it's a nice [best practice](https://www.codementor.io/@mattgoldspink/nodejs-best-practices-du1086jja#10-require-all-your-dependencies-up-front) :

```js
const fs = require('fs');
```

next for your problem, just declare a variable on the outside scope and fill it with the file content :

```
const fs = require('fs');  

function function_1() {
     var parseJson
     fs.readFile('date.json',function(err,content){
       if(err) throw err;
       parseJson = JSON.parse(content);
     })    
    
     return parseJson;
}
```

Or as @Pointy mentioned you can just use [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) that does not require a callback:

```
const fs = require('fs');  

function function_1() {
     return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('date.json'));
}
```

Comment: "just declare a variable on the outside scope and fill it with the file content" — That doesn't work!